# The reflexive and non-reflexive forms of ‘wünschen’

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun, verb-usage

What is the difference between the reflexive and non-reflexive forms of the verb *wünschen*? For example take the sentence:

> I wish you a very pleasant evening

How would I say that in German?

> Ich wünsche euch einen schönen Abend

or

> Ich wünsche mir euch einen schönen Abend.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing *reflexive* in "ich wünsche mir..." - That's simply dative.

Comment: @tofro In the third person it becomes ‘er wünscht *sich’* rather than ‘er wünscht *ihm’,* so by definition it is reflexive. I know, it seems weird.

Comment: @Jan - *reflexive* is always accusative, but "er wünscht sich" is dative. It just happens to look the same as "er wäscht sich", which is accusative and reflexive.

Comment: @tofro Basically you are saying that *sich* can be both a reflexive pronoun and a dative pronoun that references the acting individual and that these two are gramatically distinct?

Comment: @jan well, only for 3rd person it happens to be the same thing. 1st and second person have mich/mir and dich/dir. So dative and reflexive pronoun are distinct in the first two persons, so I'd assume they are *grammatically* distinct in the 3rd person, but just happen to look the same (just as in plural)

Comment: @tofro Well, I was not considering first/second person because they actually distinguish between dative and accusative but not between reflexive/nonreflexive. (The assumption being that two of the same turning up automatically makes it reflexive; there is only one *mich/dich* possible.) But I fear this is trailing too far …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these two forms exists in English or other languages, too. Basically, a lot of verbs have a ‘person they affect’ which can be somebody else (non-reflexive) or oneself (reflexive). I tend to usually ignore that two forms of these verbs exist and just remember the non-reflexive one since it is more general.

Thus, I would suggest you remember the verb as:

> jemandem etwas<sup>{akk}</sup> wünschen

With the additional information that *jemandem* can also be oneself, i.e. *sich<sup>{dat}</sup>*.

I’m not sure if verbs with two dative objects exist, but if they do they are rare. Thus, having a dative *mich* alongside a dative object *euch* should set off alarms. The only correct form is:

> Ich wünsche euch einen schönen Abend.

If you want to wish yourself a nice evening you might say:

> Ich wünsche mir einen schönen Abend.

But in this case only *you* are the recipient of the wish; nobody else can be. (Okay, they could, but that would be *mir und euch*.)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I am just still confused about the the reflexive verb, which mostly (and this is my understanding) mean a wish for the future: e.g.:
wie wünschen sich die Fauen Männer in 10 Jahren?
isn't Männer here an indirect Dativ Object?

Comment: @Millen No, *Männer* is an accusative object. You can tell this by changing it into the singular: ‘Wie wünschen sich die Frauen **ihren Mann** in 10 Jahren?’ In case you thought *die Frauen* were accusative: no, they are actually nominative and the sentence’s subject.